# How to add boost library in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

i got the following error while running my programme:
cannot open source file "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"

This is my configuration:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add boost to your build process or to IntelliSense? IntelliSense is configured in [c_cpp_properies.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference). The configuration of your build process depends on your build process. How do you build your project? Your code is not valid C++. There are no variable-length arrays (`int array[n]`). If you're using a special dialect you should add a tag for it.

Comment: Actually that source code work on codechef (a online compiler) but not on my vscode i want to configure it only so that it will work on that too.

Comment: You have to configure your build process. How do you build your project?

Comment: can you plz just tell me how can i make my compiler to detect boost library cause it is unable to detect it.

Comment: This depends on your build system. If you can't tell me how you build your project I can't tell you how you have to configure your project.

Comment: this is my configuration {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and add the code there. This looks like your c_cpp_properies.json. This file is unrelated to your build process. It only configures IntelliSense.

Comment: see now i have edited

Comment: This doesn't help because the file c_cpp_properies.json doesn't contain build configuration. How do you build your project?

Comment: i build it using intellisense and coderunner in vs code

Comment: You can't build a project using IntelliSense. Have you read the documentation? You can configure a custom command for each programming language in [`code-runner.executorMap`](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/README.md#configuration) in the file [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Code-Runner and set a custom build command in settings.json, e.g.

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "c++": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -IBOOST_INCLUDE_PATH -LBOOST_LIBRARY_PATH -lBOOST_LIBRARY1 -lBOOST_LIBRARY2 ... && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
```